# WP 7 Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP 7 App, i have to store the images and XML file of two types,

1: first type of files are not updated frequently on server so i want to store them Permanently on local storage so that when ever app starts it can access these files from local storage , and when these files are updated on server , also update local storage files.I want these files not to be deleted on application termination.

2: Second type of files are those that i want to save in isolated storage temporarily e.g. app requested a XML file from server , i stored it locally and next time if app requests same file instead of getting it from server get it from local storage , and Delete these files when the application terminates..

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Isolated Storage is designed to be used to store data that should remain permanent (until the user `uninstalls` the app). There's example code of how to write and save a file on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Therefore, any file you save (temp or not), will be stored until the user uninstalls the app or your app deletes the file.

2) For temporary data, you can use the [PhoneApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967547%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property. This will automatically delete the files after your app closes. However, there's a size limit (I belive PhoneApplicationService.State has a limit of `4mb`).

Alternatively, if the XML file is too big, you can write it to the Isolated Storage. Then, you can handle your page's [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.closing%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event and delete the file from Isolated Storage there using the [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletefile%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) method.